# UITableViewCell variables ni?

Tags: xcode, swift

I have correctly setup my tableview using a nib. I register the nib and the identifier. Somehow, I am getting a nil in my code here:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = galleryTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("GalleryCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GalleryCell
```

It then takes me to the custom cell I created and is telling me every variable is nil. I have reconnected my outlets and still receive errors.

In my custom cell, it crashes here:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    var tapPhotoAction = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("photoTap:"))
    tapPhotoAction.delegate = self
    tapPhotoAction.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    galleryPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapPhotoAction)
```

Any thoughts on why this would happen at all? It is saying galleryPhoto is nil, but it should not be. I have the outlet connected. Also, this only happens on the simulator, not on a real device.

EDIT:

I  am not using a storyboard, just a xib. I have the following code so I am not using registerClass.

```
galleryCellLoader = UINib(nibName: "GalleryCell", bundle: nil) 
galleryTable.registerNib(galleryCellLoader, forCellReuseIdentifier: "GalleryCustomCell")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched on the web for awhile now and finally found an answer to fix this problem. I did the following:

iPhone Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings...

Amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "GalleryCustomCell")
```

then click the tableView from the storyboard + ctrl , and drag the line to the view controller and register the table view. Than view controller should show

```
 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

( you should use

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```

in your view controller which have the table view, click the tableView in storyboard + ctrl and drag it to the view controller then click delegate and datasource )

then try to run the code again.

Comment: I am not using a storyboard, just a xib. I have the following code so I am not using registerClass.

galleryCellLoader = UINib(nibName: "GalleryCell", bundle: nil)
        galleryTable.registerNib(galleryCellLoader, forCellReuseIdentifier: "GalleryCustomCell")

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // PART 1 BEGIN
    let identifier = "GalleryCustomCell"
    var cell:GalleryCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? GalleryCell
    if (cell == nil){
        let nib: NSArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("GalleryCell", owner: self.galleryTable, options: nil)
        cell = nib.objectAtIndex(0) as! GalleryCell
    }
    // PART 1 END

    // PART 2 BEGIN
    // if it is required, need to assign cell's delegate
    var tapPhotoAction = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("photoTap:"))
    //tapPhotoAction.delegate = self 
    tapPhotoAction.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    cell.galleryPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapPhotoAction)
    // PART 2 END

    return cell
}
```

Use first part only and it doesn't fix it your problem. Use the entire code block. You should take care of cell's delegate also.

Comment: I will give this a shot after work today and let you know!

Comment: I have tried what you said but it is still not working. The cell is created but again all the variables are nil. It only does it on the simulator AND I have multiple tables in the app and they do not have this issue. It is hooked up the same way for every table :( Here is a link to show what my GalleryCell looks like after Part 1 completes... http://oi62.tinypic.com/jikhep.jpg

Comment: I'll updatemy code today, you can use define a new method in cell.

Comment: I will check back here tonight then. Strange that this issue occurs but only on the simulator. I tried iOS 7 and 8. iPhone 4s, 5 and 6.

Comment: The weird thing is I have IBOutlets and I have tried disconnecting and reconnecting them. When the app starts they are all nil but when I run it on a real device, they are not.